# Trailing slash in URL breaks styles in Sveltekit Static site

Tags: sveltekit

I am hoping this is a simple configuration fix that somehow I am missing. But, so far I have not been able to figure it out after hours of troubleshooting.

The problem I am having is with trailing slashes. Basically, when I add a trailing slash to the url (known or unknown) the site styles breaks. By default, Svelte removes the trailing slash. I found this issue while trying to implement a 404 page for my site and found that every time I tested an unknown route that included a `/` it would show a broken 404 page. For example https://hsnyc.co/unknown-route shows 404 fine, but https://hsnyc.co/unknown-route/ shows a broken 404 page, or any sub-route like `/unknown-route/etc1/etc2`

This happens locally and on prod. Currently hosting on Render but moving to Azure soon, url below). While running locally I have issues with a trailing slash on known and unknown paths (using `npx run build` to preview the build). On Azure, the trailing slash is handled on known URLs and they work as expected. But, it does not handle unknown paths with a trailing slash, these paths will break the page. So for example `/unknown-path` resolves to the 404 with no display issues, but `/unknown-path/` breaks the 404 page.

If you check the console, it shows mainly `MIME type` and GET errors. It seems the `_app/..`  path is being served relative to the url and not the root.

I tested this by creating a brand new Sveltekit  project with the sample app provided and the same thing happened in dev, using `npx run build` to preview the build.

Is there a way to address this in svelte or on the server? Ideally I'd like to handle any unknown routes with and without slashes so that they will go to the 404 page without causing it to break. Any help here would be appreciated.

**Project Settings:**

Static Adapter options:

```
adapter: adapter({
      pages: 'build',
      assets: 'build',
      fallback: undefined,
      precompress: false,
      strict: true
    })
```

`src/routes/+layout.js` includes the following `export const prerender = true;`

The site is currently running on: kit: `1.20.4`, svelte: `4.42`

Render : https://hsnyc.co/ 
Azure: https://kind-hill-065075d10.3.azurestaticapps.net

Comment: I see, You are using the relative path for the Style sheet (CSS) and maybe scripts too. for example ( _app/immutable/assets/1.57742c26.css). In this case with the URL is ending with slash the browser tries to download the style from address ending with slash which you do not have it, please use absolute path for the style and scripts. like ( /webRootDir/assects/css/_app/immutable/assets/1.57742c26.css).

Comment: Hi Mehrwarz, thanks for the reply. Do you know where/how I would specify the absolute path for these files in Sveltekit? In the config, the `appDir` is set to `_app` and the assets dir is set to `static` by default.  All my assets are in the 'static' dir. Thanks for your help.
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#appdir
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `paths.relative` to `false` in your svelte config:

```
kit: {
  ...

  paths: {
    relative: false,
  },

  ...
}
```

This will make the paths to your styles and scripts as root-relative (rather than relative).

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#paths

Comment: Thank you! Pavlo. This did the trick!  I had a feeling it was a configuration option that I was missing, and somehow overlooked. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Henry, you're welcome! I'm glad to hear that the solution resolved your issue :)

Setting up prerender configurations can indeed be quite a puzzle, and I can relate to that constant sense of overlooking non-obvious settings, having recently tackled a similar challenge for my own project. So, I'm glad I could help someone else.

Best of luck with your project!